# Dockerize Angular with routing and nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I am trying to Dockerize a simple Angular 9 application that has routing.

I have the following:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY /dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I run:

```
docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t ng-nexct-approval-ui-image:latest "."
docker run --rm -d  -p 4200:80/tcp --name ng-nexct-approval-ui-container ng-nexct-approval-ui-image:latest
```

When I access:

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

I get the nginx page as expected.

If I access:

```
http://localhost:4200/nexct-approval-ui/index.html
```

I get access to the index.html file in the /dist directory.

**Problem**

How do I access the Angular components?

e.g. for:

```
http://localhost:4200/login
```

and

```
http://localhost:4200/approval-edit/1573515
```

I get a `404`.

**Question**

How do I configure docker so I can access the following Angular routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path:'login', component:LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'approval-list', component: ApprovalListComponent, canActivate: [ApprovalListGuard] },
    { path: 'approval-edit/:tripId', component: ApprovalEditComponent, canActivate: [ApprovalEditGuard] }
];
```

**UPDATE**

I add the following to the **Dockerfile**:

```
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files  $uri /index.html
    }

}
```

I can access the:

```
http://localhost:4200/nexct-approval-ui/index.html
```

(but this is just a blank html file generated in the `/dist` folder on `ng build`.

If I try access any of the routes, I now get a `500`.

```
2020/07/21 15:40:35 [error] 29#29: *24 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /nexct-approval-ui/login HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:4200"

172.17.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2020:15:40:35 +0000] "GET /nexct-approval-ui/login HTTP/1.1" 500 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Surely it is pretty common to run an Angular app on a nginx server. I am struggling to find a clear answer anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you trying to achieve with `server_name _;`

Answer (score 1):

This should make it return the index.html for any URL received, and therefore all the Angular router URIs should work even when going to the URL directly rather than being redirected from an internal section of the app.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Also, make sure you're not doing anything crazy with the base_href.

Last time I did this was in Angular4 so I might be outdated :)
Hope this works for you.

---

**Edit to answer question in comment:**
The nginx.conf above will expect to find the `index.html` file under `/usr/share/nginx/html`. Depending on how the ng build is performed, you need to copy the content of the folder that contains the index file to the root location. Sometimes this is created in a nested folder under dist.

Comment: Hi Neo, thanks for the answer. When I try access `http://localhost:4200/login`, I get `"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404` and `"/usr/share/nginx/html/login" failed (2: No such file or directory)`.

Comment: If I change it to: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`, I get the following: `[error] 29#29: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:4200"

172.17.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2020:06:48:48 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 500 579 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "-"`.

Comment: This can happen if you do not have the index under the root directory `/usr/share/nginx/html` in this case

Comment: You can connect to the container and have a look if everything is there: `docker exec -ti <your-nginx-container-id> sh`, then ls  /usr/share/nginx/html

Comment: Thanks Neo, the problem was when I copied my /dist folder to nginx (see answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my Dockerfile, when I copied the /dist folder. So I changed from:

```
COPY /dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

to

```
COPY /dist/nexct-approval-ui /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and now it works